# Black screen after login to Windows Server on GCP

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, rdp

[image]

I have a problem when I launch a remote desktop that I created in Google Cloud Platform. I have a black screen and a command line on it. I can’t do anything. What is the problem and what should I do?

Comment: what to choose when creating Server Core is that Server Core? what to choose?

Comment: If you really need the graphical desktop (which you most probably don't) you need to an image with the Desktop Experience. I'd recommend to learn how to use the command line.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/WBGmwOX

help :)

Answer (score 6):

If you got used to Windows graphical UI while using Windows server you should use images that contain in the description `Server with Desktop Experience` like on the screenshot below:

[image: description]

To find more details about Server Core vs Server with Desktop Experience have a look at [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-core/what-is-server-core).

**To solve your issue** you should follow the documentation [Creating and managing Windows Server instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-managing-windows-instances) and create a new VM instance based on Windows *Server with Desktop Experience* image by using Cloud Console or gcloud command.